# How to get user's uid from their email in Firebase Firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase

I'm trying to access the user's uid from the user's email. I am coding using flutter, and am using Firebase Firestore.

Comment: You can also get from `FirebaseAuth`

Answer (score 0):

to get the uid of current user use `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid`

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work, because the user is not logged in. So basically users have to fill a two-screen sign up. The first one is for the email and password, and there i create the account, and the second one is for other info. So the user would not be logged in. Is there any other way?

Comment: i don't know any other way but you can check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63316778/how-to-get-firebase-uid-knowing-email-user it may help you